# complex sql query to be converted to rails controller

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

i had this sql query and needed to change it to rails controller

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT vendorName,startTime,endTime,appsImported,result,logfile 
             FROM appmall_dev.data_imports d order by startTime desc)as t 
             group by t.vendorNAme;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DataImport.select("vendorName,startTime,endTime,appsImported,
                   result,logfile").group("vendorName").order("startTime desc")
```